# Best way for Multiple Screen Support - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-screen-support

To support multiple screen size, what is the best way to do so ?
in my manifest, i created the

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

also i created different layout sizes and dimens

```
layout-small
layout-normal
layout-large
layout-xlarge
```

I would have to individually edit which layouts to fit all the screens.
But then some phone screen are able to detect the different screen size layout, but there's still some alignment difference. while for some phones, the layouts will go out of the screen.

Is this the correct way to do so ? or is there other alternate way  for screen support ?

so i must individually change all the layouts ? is there a better way than changing the layouts one by one ?
cause for my project, in total, i have more than 30 layouts. so if i create

```
layout-small
layout-normal
layout-large
layout-xlarge,
```

there will be more than 100 of different layouts to edit.
Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

A set of six generalized densities:-

ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

Screen Size:-

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Provide different layouts for different screen sizes:-

The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific resources are small, normal, large, and xlarge. For example, layouts for an extra-large screen should go in layout-xlarge/

For further reference use tis link:-

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late reply, and thanks for responding to me question.
So, many different size of layout will still be needed right? Just that i feel that there are to many layouts to be edit.. therefore i thought that there might be another way..

Answer (score 0):

If your layout remains the same on different screens/ orientations, I will suggest you place only one layout in the `layout` folder and use RelativeLayout or [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) to dynamically adjust content on different screen sizes. Try not to hardcode the placement of UI components (in pixels) and stick with relative positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to declare [`<supports-screens>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element) if you support all screen dimensions as they are enabled by default. I would thoroughly recommend avoiding any of these kinds of restrictive declarations.

Instead, follow the guidance for [supporting different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes), where you can choose to either WindowSizeClass with Compose or use responsive layouts in conventional Android Views.

## WindowSizeClass and Jetpack Compose

Declarative layouts using Compose are without doubt the easiest way to accomplish this, because you can pass the window size classes down as state (or through derived state to pass down) to nested composables. To [build an adaptive layout using Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/adaptive), you cound for example:

```
setContent {
    val windowSizeClass = calculateWindowSizeClass(this)
    MyApp(windowSizeClass)
}
```

Where `MyApp` can then composition the UI depending on the window size:

```
@Composable
fun MyApp(windowSizeClass: WindowSizeClass) {
    // Perform logic on the size class to decide whether to show
    // the top app bar.
    val showTopAppBar = windowSizeClass.heightSizeClass != WindowHeightSizeClass.Compact

    // MyScreen knows nothing about window sizes, and performs logic
    // based on a Boolean flag.
    MyScreen(
        showTopAppBar = showTopAppBar,
        /* ... */
    )
}
```

## Responsive layouts in Android Views

Your app's UI should be [responsive, also when using conventional Android Views](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/migrate-to-responsive-layouts), to adapt to different screen sizes as well as different orientations and device states. For instance, a navigation element could be in a sliding drawer that is off screen, but the drawer is always there:

```
<!-- res/layout/main_activity.xml -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- content view(s) -->

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        ... />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
<!-- res/layout-w600dp/main_activity.xml -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ... />

    <!-- content view(s) -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

## More reading

There's loads of material in [the "large screens" section of the Android developer site](https://developer.android.com/large-screens), including code samples, codelabs and design references.